# attaboys from petty cash

Tags: meaning, etymology

Anyone know what "take a couple of attaboys from petty cash" means, or where it comes from?

From the context it seems to be similar to "pat yourself on the back"

I googled it and found examples of it, but no real explanation of what it means.

[Examples of usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=take%20a%20couple%20of%20attaboys%20from%20petty%20cash&rlz=1C1CHBD_enGB933GB935&oq=take%20a%20couple%20of%20attaboys%20from%20petty%20cash&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: *From the context it seems to be...* Please tell us the context and the source.

Comment: [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=take+a+couple+of+attaboys+from+petty+cash&rlz=1C1CHBD_enGB933GB935&oq=take+a+couple+of+attaboys+from+petty+cash&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***attaboy***

> —used to express encouragement, approval, or admiration

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attaboy)

---

***take a couple of attaboys from petty cash***

As far as I can determine, this is still a very recent coining of a phrase. The earliest example [dates to 2003](https://forums.geocaching.com/GC/index.php?/topic/24250-commendation-for-a-geocacher/), and the phrase is mostly found on discussion forums, primarily gaming.

It does not appear on ngrams viewer, and is seen on [only a few google books searches](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=few%20attaboys%20out%20of%20petty%20cash).

It basically is a form of congratulating someone for an accomplishment, but does not necessarily  mean to take money from petty cash: it simply is a suggestion that the person should reward themselves in some way for a good job well done.

Comment: Presumably derived from the, I think, dated congratulation "Attaboy!" uttered when someone has done something praiseworthy such as made a good stroke in a ball game.

Comment: See https://www.etymonline.com/word/attaboy#etymonline_v_18900.

Comment: +1 There is something potentially derisive in the usage, it seems to me, although the speaker may intend that the expression be taken as a compliment. I am reminded of the expression "That and [some rapidly increasing sum of cash] will buy me a cup of coffee" (said in response to someone who offers praise instead of money for the person's efforts). The notion that the "attaboys" come "from petty cash" implies that their source is a kind of slush fund of light praise to be be disbursed on incidental occasions when the work done doesn't merit a monetary reward.

Comment: It's hard to know if it's patronising/derisive or not. It seems similar to other expressions like "give yourself a chocolate medal" or as mentioned "give yourself a pat on the back", which aren't really particularly congratulatory although they can be said in a nice way. There's actually a long discussion on [Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/162747/how-to-praise-other-peoples-work-without-sounding-patronizing-or-insincere) about how to congratulate someone without sounding patronising, so it's evidently difficult.